# Laravel 8 - SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No such file or directory

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-sail

I'm trying to make a project using Laravel and Sail but I'm getting errors when I'm trying to migrate or do anything related to the project's database (for example, seeding).

More specifically, when using `artisan sail migrate` or anything related, I'm getting the following errors:

When `DB_HOST=localhost` in my `.env` file:

`SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No such file or directory (SQL: select * from information_schema.tables where table_schema = noway and table_name = migrations and table_type = 'BASE TABLE')`

When `DB_HOST=127.0.0.1` in my `.env` file:

`SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection refused (SQL: select * from information_schema.tables where table_schema = noway and table_name = migrations and table_type = 'BASE TABLE')`

What I've tried:

- changing the `DB_HOST` to localhost and 127.0.0.1 (most common answer online, no succes)
- making sure SQL is running
- clearing cache for `sail artisan migrate`
- `./vendor/bin/sail down --rmi all -v` to remove all images and volumes
- changing username and password and putting them between '' or ""

None of the above have been of succes.

Answer (score 4):

Did you run `./vendor/bin/sail up` after creating and setting `.env`?

If not, please execute `./vendor/bin/sail down --rmi all -v` to remove all images and volumes and then just ran `./vendor/bin/sail up` to recreate the images and volumes.

Also as per Laravel docs https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/sail you can connect to db by setting env DB_HOST to `mysql`

Answer (score 1):

T had the same problem with pretty much the same conditions:
-I started with a laravel project then moved it to sail

the way I solved this was by adding an entry `DB_PORT=3306` in the .env file and changed `DB_HOST=localhost` to `DB_HOST=mysql`  as described in laravel docs : https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/sail#mysql

- don't forget to check the new credentials that sail uses by default

Comment: especialy when you using DOCKER `host` can be/is a service name in docker-compose file